# Regular expression for extracting the city name from string pattern

Tags: java, javascript, ruby-on-rails, regex

I wanted to extract the city name from the following example patterns.

1. Philadelphia.json
2. Philadelphia
3. Washington D.C..json
4. Upstate New York.json

Only one regex. should be suitable for all the above patterns to extract the city name.

.json in the end is optional. It will only come if it is the API call, in case of HTML request it will not come.

The output is expected as follows:

1. Philadelphia
2. Philadelphia
3. Washington D.C.
4. Upstate New York

Please help me on this.

Comment: What attempts to achieve this have you made?

Comment: Following is my example string: http://example.com/account_lists/1050-UserName-Philadelphia.json OR http://example.com/account_lists/1050-UserName-Philadelphia  So from this I wanted to extract the city, I need to define the routes for this. Washington D.C. creating an issue since '.' has come in the URL. So writing the regular expression to allow '.' is the only solution.

Comment: Upstate New York? The city of Upstate New York? Also, you just want to remove a trailing `.json`?

Comment: is regex compulsory? you can do it without regex in two lines..

Comment: you can do it without regex also .                                      var str = s.indexOf(".json") != -1 ? s.substr(0,s.indexOf(".json")) : s;

Comment: Elliott Frisch: .json is the optional, so what I want is regex should extract the city name from string. String could contain space, dot, -, digits and characters as I have give the examples.

Comment: Code_Cracker: I need regex. since I need to define the route, so regex is the only solution. I have following route defined "match '/account_lists/:user_id-:user_name-:market_name' => 'account_lists#key_account_show', constraints: {market_name: /[^\/]*/}, as: :account_lists_key_account_show, via: :get" The current regex (/[^\/]*/) in routes extract the market name as "Philadelphia.json" if its JSON request, In html request works fine and gives the market name as "Philadelphia" which is fine. The only problem is in .json request it should give me the market name as "Philadelphia".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^([A-Z][\s\w.,-]+?)(?=\.json|$)
```

Try this .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/38

Comment: it  matches underscore and new line characters also. And also the names which start with small letters. http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/37

Comment: @AvinashRaj where in question is it mentioned that name start can only be capitol?

Comment: , and - should also take.

Comment: City names must starts with a capital letter and also in his examples there was not small letters at the start.

Comment: @ChetanKalore `-` and `,`included

Comment: I am not sure why so much regex is being used instead of just `yourString.replace(/\.json$/,"");`.. or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

#### Without Regex:

```
yourString = (yourString.lastIndexOf(".json") > -1)?yourString.slice(0,-5):yourString;
```

#### With Regex:

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/\.json$/,"");
```

Comment: This works only on "Philadelphia.json" and not on "Philadelphia"

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to match only the city names which are present at the start.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(?: [A-Z]\.[A-Z]\.?|(?: [A-Z][a-z]+)*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iH8jE7/3)

**OR**

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+[ .A-Za-z]*?(?=\.json|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iH8jE7/4)

Comment: Avinash: You are very close, what I am expecting. The only problem with city "Washington D.C." Using your regex. dot after C is not getting selected. In our database city name is "Washington D.C."

Comment: @ChetanKalore I added another option also.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
String test = "Philadelphia.json";      // or any other input string
    String replaced = test.replace(".json", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

If regex isn't necessary then this simple one line function will do the work for you:

```
function removeJson(s){
        return s.replace('.json','');
}
alert(removeJson("Philadelphia.json")); //"Philadelphia"
alert(removeJson("Philadelphia"));      //"Philadelphia"
```

Pass any string to it and you will have .json removed if its there.

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/xggugk80/)**

Comment: Abdul: I need regex. since I need to define the route, so regex is the only solution. I have following route defined "match '/account_lists/:user_id-:user_name-:market_name' => 'account_lists#key_account_show', constraints: {market_name: /[^\/]*/}, as: :account_lists_key_account_show, via: :get" The current regex (/[^\/]*/) in routes extract the market name as "Philadelphia.json" if its JSON request, In html request works fine and gives the market name as "Philadelphia" which is fine. The only problem is in .json request it should give me the market name as "Philadelphia".

Comment: .json is the optional, so what I want is regex should extract the city name from string. String could contain space, dot, -, digits and characters as I have give the examples above in my question.

Comment: you can pass your complete regex expression to my function and get the string free from .json (it's optional, if it wasn't present, string won't be harmed)